# DOMException: Could not start video source - chrome 85 update

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

I had a working webrtc application which stops to work, today. Since there is no change on the code, and with new update of chrome, I thought this will experience by whole webrtc community, and it's worthy to ask here for a sulotion. 
That's a typical usage of `getUserMedia` which tries to access the webcam and microphone:

```
let constraints = {
  audio: true,
  video: true
}
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function (stream) {//something}
.catch(function (err) {//something}
```

when I try to access the mic and webcam as before, I NOW encounter to this error: (which is not meaningful to me)

```
DOMException: Could not start video source
```

Why cannot start video source? how to avoid (or fix) this problem? 
**Worth to mention this code is working fine until version 85 of chrome.** 
Thanks a lot for your kindness and help.

Comment: file a chrome bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry
set the component to Blink>GetUserMedia and provide a https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py or much more details about your camera model, e.g. from chrome://media-internals.

Comment: thanks a lot, done that. here is the link: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1128913